# Android - Using keys to query nodes (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where I use the `GoogleMaps` functionality. So in my application I am able to draw a path between two markers and also set regular markers on the map.

The database structure that I have is:

- One path can have multiple markers
- One marker has one route

To handle this I have a database structure as follows:

[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to use the keys from the `markerId` node to `query` the appropriate markers in the `markers` node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("routes").child("-KzdUTraH1BodJMuEnSu").child("markerId");
ValueEventListener ref=new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String x=data.getKey();

        DatabaseReference datas=database.getReference().getInstance().child("markers");
        datas.orderByKey().equalTo(x).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //code here
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
               throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
};
reference.addValueEventListener(ref);
```

In the first query, you are querying on location `markerId`, then you get the key inside the `for loop` and use the key in the other query to check if it is the same key inside node `markers`

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit, without changing its meaning. One thing I'm not sure of is the loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`. I think you mean that loop to end after the nested listener, is that correct?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes that's true, I have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterHaddad, thanks for your answer. Quick question: Does this only get `one` marker from the `marker node` or does it get all three?

Comment: @JDoe it enters the markerid and gets all three, then it checks if any of those three is equalto a key inside `markers`, then you can retrieve or do any code inside onDataChange